# UIButton SetTitle text alignment

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to set the title of a UIButton programmatically, but the title appears on the side of the button instead of on it.

Usually it works fine, and I wonder weather the fact that this application is in landscape mode only, might have something to do with it?

```
btn.SetTitle ("my text", UIControlState.Normal);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: what do you mean "the title appears on the side of the button"?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
myUITextObject.textAlignment = .Center
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also try this

```
[btn setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
```

This should center the content (horizontally).

if you are now using iOS 6 or higher, UITextAlignmentCenter has been deprecated.So using NSTextAlignmentCenter instead of UITextAlignmentCenter.